# C++ template C2039

Tags: c++, templates

This compiles:

```
template <class T>
class Bar {};

template<class T, class Dummy=void>
class Foo;

template<class T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Bar<T>, T>::value
>::type> {
    public:
        //THIS CHANGES IN THE 2ND SNIPPET
        void test () const {
            std::cout << "test";
        }
};

class Cat : Bar<Cat> {};

int main () {
    Foo<Cat> foo;
    foo.test();
    return 0;
}
```

This errors:

```
template <class T>
class Bar {};

template<class T, class Dummy=void>
class Foo;

template<class T>
class Foo <T, typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Bar<T>, T>::value
>::type> {
    public:
        //THIS CHANGED!
        void test () const;
};

//THIS WAS ADDED SINCE THE 1ST SNIPPET!
template<class T>
void Foo<T>::test () const {
    std::cout << "test";
} //error C2039: 'test' : is not a member of 'Foo<T>'

class Cat : Bar<Cat> {};

int main () {
    Foo<Cat> foo;
    foo.test();
    return 0;
}
```

I have marked the differences. **Why does it error in the 2nd code snippet? How do I keep declaration and definition separate while avoiding the error?**

I'm guessing it's got something to do with this:
"template
void Foo::test () const"

Like, this is the wrong way to tell the compiler that the method **test() const** is a method of **template class template class Foo , T>::value >::type>**

I've, of course, looked it up on Google and StackOverflow but it seems that, whenever this error pops up for templates, it's a different reason every time. (Probably because a lot of things can cause the C2039 error.)

Also, could a mod. or someone help me add the **C2039** tag to this post? It says I need a min. of 1500 rep. to add that tag.

-- Rambling --
It also be noted that it's been a while since I've used C++; and even longer since I've used templates. I know this might be a weird way to use templates but I can assure you I have a valid reason!

Comment: There's a reason for you needing 1500 rep. We don't have a tag for every MSVC compiler error code.

Comment: And your class has two template parameters, but your function definition is for a class with one.

Comment: Yes.. I do realize that. But I have two declarations for template Foo. One is with two template parameters, the other with just one. The first code-snippet instantiates the 2nd template class (as expected) which was what I was trying to do. I'm just wondering how I can separate declaration and definition =/

Comment: Foo<int> foo; //Fails as expected because int does not inherit from Bar<int>; I only want to instantiate Foo<T> when T inherits from Bar<T>. I managed to get it to work. I just need to find a way to separate declaration and definition of methods in the template class =/

Comment: I believe you have to put the same `enable_if` in the definition. Bet you wish constraints were here.

Comment: Try searching for documentation on the errors first before coming here. There's usually code examples at MSN for compiler errors like [C2039](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdwb3fd7(v=vs.80).aspx). There's always a limited number of ways errors can be triggered.

Comment: I looked through the documentation, which is how I guessed that I was, somehow, defining the method wrongly. I just didn't know how to get it right. @chris just gave me the answer, though. I tested it and it worked. I cannot believe I'm going to have to copy-paste that std::enable_if<> bit of code all over the place. Oh, gawd. All that pointless meta-data. Yes, if you're talking about C# constraints =/ Is there a way around this? If there isn't, I guess I'll have to ready my Ctrl, C and V buttons..

Comment: @JustinAnyhowStep, Honestly, it's a lot better looking defined inline. I'm not even sure whether constraints can help this much. `template<typename T> requires IsBaseOf<Bar<T>, T>`-ish support seems slightly unlikely to me for now.

Comment: You should put your comments in an answer so I can mark it as the correct one. Yeah, I know it'll be less messy inline but it makes it harder for my poor eyes to see the methods I can call if the definitions are inline. Not sure how to say this.. But I like headers without definitions in them so I can see the general outline of the class easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of out-of-class member declaration for a partially specialized class template is given in 14.5.4.3/1 (C++03). And this is what it looks like

```
// primary template
template<class T, int I> struct A {
  void f();
};

// class template partial specialization
template<class T> struct A<T,2> {
  void g();
};

// member of class template partial specialization
template<class T> void A<T,2>::g() { }
```

As you can see, you have to specify specialized arguments in the out-of-class member definition.

In your case it should be

```
template<class T>
void Foo<T, typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_base_of<Bar<T>, T>::value>::type>::test () const {
    std::cout << "test";
}
```